# Subtract date in yyyy-ww format

Tags: oracle

The scenario is, i have given_date in yyyy-ww format, i.e.,201243 and `current_week` is 201338

i also have a week_number say 50, this indicates 50 weeks...

now i should add this 50 weeks to 201243 so that it gives me the result as 201341, and the logic is i should check if its greater then 201338

I've written a piece of code... for this...

```
Process_date= diff_yyyyww(current_week,given_date);

if Process_date>(48+week_number)
...
...
```

instead of adding 50, if I find (difference between the given_date & current_week) and check it with (48+week_number)

Its working fine...

I need justification for this **"48"**, if I add number 48 I'm getting the expected result...

Comment: Dates don't have a "format". What datatype does that column have?

Comment: number(6), i cant use date data type here...date here is in year week format...

Comment: 48 is the magic number of `0` character. Maybe there's some conversion from int to char happening somehow?

Comment: What is `diff_yyyyww` doing - what does it give you for your example weeks?

Comment: tmp_val_1        NUMBER;    
   tmp_val_2        NUMBER;    
BEGIN    
   tmp_val_1 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_1/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_1, 100);   
   tmp_val_2 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_2/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_2, 100);    
   RETURN (tmp_val_1 - tmp_val_2);

Comment: @Guru - so for your values that gives you 47, right? What is the relevance of that number? It's less than `48+week_number`, clearly, so... what? I'm missing something still.

Comment: Question explained in detail Actually the flow should be like Assume, current_week=201338; Given_Date=201240; Given_weeks_to_add=50;--constant if (Given_Date+Given_weeks_to_add)>current_week then ... ... end if;

Comment: -- here i did not know how to add Given_Date+Given_weeks_to_add so i ve written like Process_date= diff_yyyyww(current_week,given_date); if Process_date>(48+week_number) ... ... end if; where diff_yyyyww(in_yyyyww_1,in_yyyyww_2); does the following tmp_val_1 NUMBER; tmp_val_2 NUMBER; BEGIN tmp_val_1 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_1/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_1, 100); tmp_val_2 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_2/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_2, 100); RETURN (tmp_val_1 - tmp_val_2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WW` gives you the [week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#r42c1-t59).

Today is `201338`. If you treated that as a number and added 50 to it, you'd get `201388`, and there is clearly no week 88. Any combinations of `given_week` and `week_number` which would give you a calculated answer where the week appears to be > 53 would be a problem, so you're deciding when to treat the values a bit differently.

Effectively you're treating the this as a number where the first four digits are in base 10 and the last two and a single value in base 53. By adding 48 to the week number you're seeing whether it wraps around past 53 and if it does you're starting again at week 1 of the following year. Adding 48 to `201388` gives `201436`, which looks like a more sensible value. It's effectively skipped over the invalid week numbers between 54 and 00.

So basically you're using 48 because 48+53 = 101, I think.

With your values, `process_date` looks like it ought to be doing `to_number('201338') - to_number('201243')`, which is 95, but that is not greater than (48 + 50), so it must be doing something else. I'm not quite following your logic, or where the current date fits into the picture, really.

I suspect this isn't going to work if `week_number` is itself greater the 53, since you don't seem to be trying to deal with it wrapping over two year-ends.

You could instead convert to a nominal date, add the required number of weeks in days, and convert back. That might not always align though, it would need some testing to make sure it meets your expectations, particularly in case you 'lose' a week somewhere:

```
var given_date varchar2(6);
var week_number number;
exec :given_date := '201243';
exec :week_number := 50;

select to_char(to_date(substr(:given_date, 1, 4) || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD')
  + (to_number(substr(:given_date, 5, 2)) * 7) + (:week_number * 7)
  , 'YYYYWW') as answer
from dual;

ANSWER
------
201341
```

You can't use `WW` directly in a `to_date` so I'm picking the first day of that week, essentially; the first day of `201201` is `2012-01-01`, and adding 43 weeks to that gives `2012-10-28`. Adding a further 50 weeks to that gives `2013-10-13`, which is in week `201341`.

Comment: Question explained in detail Actually the flow should be like Assume, 
    current_week=201338;
    Given_Date=201240;
    Given_weeks_to_add=50;--constant 
    if (Given_Date+Given_weeks_to_add)>current_week 
    then 
    ... 
    ... 
    end if;

Comment: -- here i did not know how to add Given_Date+Given_weeks_to_add    
so i ve written like    
    
    
Process_date= diff_yyyyww(current_week,given_date);    
    
if Process_date>(48+week_number)    
...    
...    
end if;    
    
where   
    
diff_yyyyww(in_yyyyww_1,in_yyyyww_2);    
    
does the following    
    
tmp_val_1 NUMBER;    
tmp_val_2 NUMBER;     
BEGIN tmp_val_1 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_1/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_1, 100);     
tmp_val_2 := FLOOR(in_yyyyww_2/100) * 52 + MOD(in_yyyyww_2, 100);     
RETURN (tmp_val_1 - tmp_val_2);

Comment: hi @Alex if I give given_date := '201255'; this query gives output as 201401,
actually there are 52 weeks in a year & 201255 is not possible....
correct me if i m wrong

Comment: @Guru - There are 52 full weeks plus 1 or 2 extra days (depending on leap year), but there are 53 weeks for `WW` as indicated above; `select to_char(date '2013-12-31', 'YYYYWW') from dual;` gives `201353`. But `201255` is not valid week, no, so where did you get that from? Are you having to deal with bad data too? What should happen?